# Naming quaternary alkylammonium cations

Tags: nomenclature

Which is the correct name, (1) or (2), for the following cation?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [*Nomenclature of Organic Chemistry: IUPAC Recommendations and Preferred Names 2013 (Blue Book)*](https://doi.org/10.1039/9781849733069) (**P-62.6.1**),

> Salts of tetravalent nitrogen $\ce{R4N+X-}$ (where one $\ce{R}$ group represents the parent hydride of the amine or imine and the other groups are hydrogen atoms or substituent groups) are named by one of the following methods:
>
> (1) by adding the suffix 'ium' to the name of the amine or imine, with elision of the terminal letter, 'e' if present, substituent groups being cited as prefixes, and the name of the anion added as a separate word;
> (2) by substituting the parent hydride 'azanium', $\ce{NH4+}$;
> (3) by substituting the parent hydride 'ammonium', $\ce{NH4+}$, for quaternary salts only.
>
> Method (1) leads to preferred IUPAC names.

The form of the names you suggested use the third of these: that is, the names are based on the parent hydride "ammonium" with a number of substituents. Since the cation in question is quaternary (i.e. doesn't have a free $\ce{NH}$), this is an acceptable method of naming the cation, although it's not the preferred name.

So, time to address the question proper. As given in **P-14.5**, substituents are cited in "alphanumerical order":

> Simple prefixes (i.e., those describing atoms and unsubstituted substituents) are arranged alphabetically; multiplicative prefixes, if necessary, are then inserted and do not alter the alphabetical order already established.

The prefixes "butyl" and "ethyl" are already preferred prefixes (**P-29.3.2.1**), so we are good on that front. Since "butyl" comes before "ethyl" alphabetically, "butyl" is cited first in the name. The "tri" prefix indicating three ethyls is not taken into consideration, leading to the correct name **butyltriethylammonium**.

The Blue Book, in fact, further specifies that "ethyl" should be placed within brackets (**P-16.5.1.3**):

> Parentheses are placed around prefixes denoting simple substituent groups in front of parent hydrides when no locants are necessary and around prefixes defining simple substituent groups qualified by locants. A minimum of parentheses must be used. Enclosing marks are never used around the name of the first cited simple substituent group.

This leads to a "more correct" name of **butyltri(ethyl)ammonium**. However, the parentheses are only mandatory in preferred IUPAC names (**P-16.5**), and as established above, names based on "ammonium" are not preferred IUPAC names:

> Enclosing marks must not be omitted from preferred IUPAC names. In general nomenclature, when there is no possible ambiguity, enclosing marks may be omitted to simplify a name.

In this case, I don't think that there is any ambiguity introduced by dropping the parentheses, so the original name **butyltriethylammonium** is still acceptable, albeit not preferred.

The *preferred* IUPAC name would be derived using method (1) in the first quote. There are a few more rules to look up, but I will not quote them here. Application of these leads to the preferred name ***N*,*N*,*N*-triethylbutan-1-aminium**.

Answer (score 2):

If you name two groups that are the same in priority, name it alphabetically. Since b comes before e, butyl is before ethyl. The first answer is correct.